# Fixed positioning doesn't work in Chrome 16 but does in FF and Safari

Tags: google-chrome, position, fixed

I'm working on a site that has a fixed position "sticky sidebar" with issues on Chrome on Mac OS X.

The culprit is the #sidebar which changes to fixed positioning via jQuery once the page hits 198 pixels. The big mystery is the sidebar works as intended on our category page http://buyitalready.com/c/health-and-beauty but not the front page http://buyitalready.com/

I've inspected the code with a diff tool and to my knowledge it's pretty much the same markup.

It was working fine until, I suspect, Chrome 16 was released. I've currently tested it on the latest Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, and it seems to be broken only on Chrome.

Any help is appreciated! Many thanks.